# How to have dynamic routing in datapower

Tags: websphere, ibm-datapower

Well I am quite new to datapower(IBM Websphere xi50) and i have got struck as to how to route dynamically.Suppose we have configured dynamic backend then a client asks for some service so how to route it .

Is it through XSLT or yhrough certain policy creation I am not getting any clear idea regarding it?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do it through XSLT . The steps to do it is as following (logically)

> Step 1: Determine the criteria based on which you want routing [it could be URI or any part of message]
>   Step 2: Use datapower built in function *dp:open-url* to send traffic to target. 
>   Step 3: Get the response and process it.

There are other ways to do it as well but this is the most straight forward way.

Comment: URL-OPEN is not efficient way for dynamic routing. It can be used only for orchestration.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you use "var://service/routing-url" and not as Ajitabh answered "dp:url-open".

You can also use the "Set variable" action instead of XSLT.

dp:url-open is used to "fork" a message, not to route it. If you use dp:url-opento route you must also set "skip-backside = 1"!

See sample for XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="destURL" select="concat('http://127.0.0.1:',$Transformer-port,'/', $usrTransformer)" />
<!-- Set backend URL -->
<dp:set-variable name="'var://service/routing-url'" value="$destURL" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can "set variable" rule in the applicable policy var://service/mpgw/skip-backside=1. I would recommend that instead of doing this in XSLT/Gateway scripts as this is more visible and people can know your intention right away by looking at the rule.

Answer (score 0):

I create an XSLT that looks at the different elements in the incoming message to help determine the destination. I then invoked the DataPower extension method <dp:set-variable('var://service/routing-url') select="yourUrlHere"/>. I put that XSLT into a routing action.